# Diplaying Dynamic Percentage and Quantity Value in ggplot in Shiny Dashboard when values changes on user input

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm trying to display both percentages and quantity labels in ggplot in shiny dashboard, which should update as per the input by the user for the ggplot.

My Data set looks like this :

```
Week      Region   Flag    Warehouse  TAT       Quantity 
2021-W01  North    Local   ABC        In TAT    10
2021-W01  North    Local   ABC        Out TAT   5
2021-W01  East     Local   ABC        In TAT    13
2021-W01  East     Local   ABC        Out TAT   6
2021-W02  West     UPC     XYZ        In TAT    15
2021-W02  West     UPC     XYZ        Out TAT   10
```

Here Week is the Week number of the year, Region represents the North/East/West/South, Flag has only two values Local and UPC which is movement type, Warehouse represents the different warehouses, TAT column shows the performance part. If it is In tat the performance is good and if it is out the performance is bad.

What I have achieved by now :

I have been able to create the plot and filter in shiny dashboard which updates as per the user input. But I'm unable to add lables to it which will dynamically change to the user input.

[image]

Code:

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
library(gtools)

ui <- shinyUI(
  
  navbarPage(
    title = 'Dashboard',
    
    tabPanel('Performance',
             tabsetPanel(
               tabPanel('View1',
                        selectInput('warehouse', 'Select Warehouse', unique(plot1$shipment_fc)), 
                        selectInput('region', 'Select Region', unique(plot1$regional_zone)),
                        selectInput('mov_type', 'Select Movement Type', unique(plot1$flag)),
                        fluidRow(
                          plotlyOutput("myplot_fwd")
                        )
               ),
               tabPanel('View 2'
               )
             ))
    
    
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$myplot_fwd <- renderPlotly({
    plot1 <- read.csv("plot1.csv", sep = ",", header = TRUE)
    
        data <- plot1 %>%
  filter(Warehouse == input$warehouse, Region == input$region, flag == input$mov_type)

p<- ggplot(data, aes(fill=TAT, y=Quantity, x=Week)) + 
  geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity",colour="black") + 
  labs(x = "Week") +
  labs(y = "Percentage") +
  labs(title = "Performance") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent) 
 p <- ggplotly(p, tooltip="text")
    p
    
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I tried to update my renderplotly part to show percentages:

```
  output$myplot_fwd <- renderPlotly({
    plot1 <- read.csv("plot1.csv", sep = ",", header = TRUE)
    
    data <- plot1 %>%
      filter(Warehouse == input$warehouse, Region == input$region, flag == input$mov_type)
    
    p<- ggplot(data, aes(fill=TAT, y=Quantity, x=Week)) + 
      geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity",colour="black") + 
      labs(x = "Week") +
      labs(y = "Percentage") +
      labs(title = "Performance") +
      scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent) +
    geom_text(aes(label = Quantity), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
    geom_text(data = . %>%
                filter(Warehouse == input$warehouse, Region == input$region,flag == input$flag) %>%
                group_by(Week,TAT) %>%
                mutate(p = Quantity / sum(Quantity)) %>%
                ungroup(),
              aes(y = p, label = scales::percent(p)),
              position = position_stack(vjust = 3.25),
              show.legend = FALSE)
    p <- ggplotly(p, tooltip="text")
    p
    
  })
```

But this is displaying wrong results and ruining the plot
eg :

[image]

Is there a way i can correctly display labels of Percentages and if possible Quantity also in GGplot.
Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
output$myplot_fwd <- renderPlotly({
    plot1 <- read.csv("plot1.csv", sep = ",", header = TRUE)
    
    data <- plot1 %>%
      filter(Warehouse == input$warehouse, Region == input$region, Flag == input$mov_type) %>%
      group_by(Week) %>% 
      mutate(label = prop.table(Quantity) * 100)
    
    
    p <- ggplot(data, aes(fill=TAT, y=label, x=Week, label  = paste0(round(label, 2), '%'))) + 
      geom_col(colour="black") + 
      labs(x = "Week") +
      labs(y = "Percentage") +
      labs(title = "Performance") +
      geom_text(position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
    
    p <- ggplotly(p, tooltip="text")
    p
    
  })
```